# Color a pixel in the div

Tags: css, html, colors

I don't know if it is tricky.

Here is a [jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/m3GMc/) simple `<div>hello</div>`:

Is there any easy way to color the top left pixel of that div in red?

Thank you.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can do this :

```
div:before{
    position: absolute;
    width:1px;height:1px;
    background:red;
    content:'';
}
div {
    position: relative;
    border:1px solid green;
    height:200px;
    background-color:yellow;
}
```

[Demonstration](http://jsfiddle.net/eqPEg/) (with a bigger red dot, so that it's obvious)

Comment: thank you for your answer. What about (n,m) coordinate in the div? I'd like to colorize the whole div.

Answer (score 0):

You should be able to use:

```
first-pixel-color-top-left-color: #f00;
```

Answer (score 0):

For browser compatibility you could add a span inside your div:

```
<div><span></span>hello</div>
```

Then add styling:

```
div {
    border:1px solid green;
    height:200px;
    background-color:yellow;
    position:relative;
}

div span {
    position:absolute;
    height:1px;
    width:1px;
    background:red;
    top:0;
    left:0;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

By this way :

```
div {
    position: relative;
    border:1px solid green;
    height:200px;
    background-color:yellow;
}

div span {
    position: absolute;
    top: 0;
    left: 0;
    height: 1px;
    width: 1px;
    background: red;
}
```

http://jsfiddle.net/m3GMc/1/

Or via an image.